# How does this line of ARM work?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am having some trouble figuring how this assembly code works. I know it loops 16 times and updates the total every iteration. Specifically on the line at the .L2 label, wouldn't that give a segmentation fault since the previous line: ldr ip, [ip, #0] reassigns ip? Can someone explains how this works? Thank you in advance for your time.

```
.L5:
    .word data
    .word total
_start:
    ldr ip, .L5
    mov r1, #0
    ldr r0, .L5+4
    mov r3, r1
    mov r2, r1
    ldr ip, [ip, #0]
    str r1, [r0, #0]
.L2:
    ldr r1, [ip, r3]
    add r3, r3, #4
    cmp r3, #64
    add r2, r2, r1
    str r2, [r0, #0]
    bne .L2
```

Comment: WTH? It's exact the same question I answered yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085378/what-does-this-arm-assembly-program-do

Comment: Besides, the accepted answer is somewhat misleading here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

- Loads the addresses of `data` in `ip` and the address of `total` in `r0`.
- Zeroes registers `r1`, `r2` and `r3`
- Loads into `ip` the contents of `data`, replacing the previous contents (the address of `data`). This does not segfault. You are allowed to load from memory into any register, including the one you just used to specify the effective address for the load. All that happens is the usual: Whatever old value was there (in this case, the pointer) is replaced with the new value (the pointee).
- Stores `0` into `total`.
- Repeats 16 times:

  - Using `ip` as the base address of an array of integers, load into `r1` the integer at offset `r3` from the base address.
  - Accumulate `r1` into the register `r2`.
  - Store `r2` to `total`.

Based on this, I believe that `data` is of type `int*` and that `total` is of type `int`. Therefore, my interpretation of your assembler is:

*Pseudocode-y C-like assembler*

```
int* data;
int total;


void start(void){
    int** ip = &data;
    int*  r0 = &total;
    int r1=0, r2=r1, r3=r1;

    int* ipnew = *ip;
    *r0 = r1;/* total = 0; */

    do{
        r1 = *(int*)((char*)ipnew + r3);/* r1 = ipnew[r3/4]; */
        r3 += 4;
        r2 += r1;
        *r0 = r2;/* total = r2; */
    }while(r3 != 64);
}
```

*Pure C*

```
int* data;
int  total;

void start(void){
    int* arr = data;      /* ip */
    register int  sum = 0;/* r2 */
    register int  i   = 0;/* r3, divided by 4 */

    total = 0;

    do{
        sum   += arr[i++];/* r1 contains the value loaded from the array. */
        total  = sum;     /* r0 contains &total */
    }while(i != 16);
}
```

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to upvote and accept my answer if you find that it has solved your problem.